# How to disable Omnisharp repeating warning popups?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, omnisharp

In Visual Studio Code I have a popup that does not ends popping up:

not sure what extension pops it up: ms-dotnettools.csharp or Omnisharp, I have in the output log

> [Warn  - 12:10:45 PM] [LanguageServerProjectSystem]Warning while loading c:\proj\myproj\src\myproj.Web\myproj.Web.csproj: The target framework 'net5.0' is out of support and will not receive security updates in the future. Please refer to https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-support for more information about the support policy.
> [Info  - 12:10:45 PM] [LanguageServerProjectSystem]Completed (re)load of all projects in 00:00:01.4545543

This message appears every two seconds in VS and output logs, I already hate it.
[image]
I don't want to update actually from .net 5, so I would like to disable this annoying warning.

here is my Omnisharp.csharp settings from VSCode

```
"omnisharp.path": "latest",
"omnisharp.useEditorFormattingSettings": false,
"csharp.suppressBuildAssetsNotification": true,
"csharp.suppressDotnetRestoreNotification": true,
"csharp.showOmnisharpLogOnError": false,
"csharp.suppressDotnetInstallWarning": true,
"csharp.suppressProjectJsonWarning": true,
"omnisharp.loggingLevel": "error",
"csharp.unitTestDebuggingOptions": {

}
```

## Github issue opened

https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/issues/6125